# Peewee, MySQL and INSERT IGNORE

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, orm, peewee

I use Peewee as ORM in a little Python script with a MySQL DB.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#coding: utf-8

import peewee
from peewee import *

db = MySQLDatabase(**config)
class Foo(peewee.Model):
    bar = peewee.CharField(unique=True, null=False)
    class Meta:
        database = db

try:
    Foo.create_table()
except:
    pass

foo_data = [{'bar':'xyz'},{'bar':'xyz'}]
Foo.insert_many(foo_data).on_conflict(action='IGNORE').execute()
```

As you can see, I have the same key. I'd like to ignore it the second time using the `on_conflict` method ([described in the API reference](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#UpdateQuery.on_conflict), but only for SQLite3), but I have this error when running the script (normal, because not implemented for MySQL):

```
peewee.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR IGNORE INTO `foo` (`bar`) VA' at line 1")
```

If I remove the `.on_conflict(action='IGNORE')`, MySQL doesn't like it either (duplicate key). How can I make peewee insert a new key or ignore it if it's a duplicate key?

Answer (score 1):

use `db.__str__()`. It returns

```
<peewee.MySQLDatabase object at 0x7f4d6a996198>
```

if the connection database is MySQL and

```
<peewee.SqliteDatabase object at 0x7fd0f4524198>
```

if the connection database is Sqlite.

So you can use an if statement like:

```
if 'SqliteDatabase' in db.__str__():
    Foo.insert_many(foo_data).on_conflict(action='IGNORE').execute()
elif 'MySQLDatabase' in db.__str__():
    try:
        Foo.insert_many(foo_data).execute() # or whatever you want with MySQL
    except:
        pass
```

I think for the MySQL database you can do something like this:

```
for data in foo_data:
    for k,v in data.items():
        if (Foo.select(Foo.bar).where(Foo.bar == v).count()) == 0:
            Foo.insert(bar=v).execute()
```

So this can be:

```
if 'SqliteDatabase' in db.__str__():
    Foo.insert_many(foo_data).on_conflict(action='IGNORE').execute()
elif 'MySQLDatabase' in db.__str__():
    with db.atomic():
        for data in foo_data:
            for k, v in data.items():
                if (Foo.select(Foo.bar).where(Foo.bar == v).count()) == 0:
                    Foo.insert(bar=v).execute()
```